# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when using BotDetect Captcha

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, captcha

I've used BotDetect before to utilize a captcha on an asp `WEBFORM`, but now when I try to add BotDetect to another Asp `WEBFORM` project using NuGet, I'm greeted with an 'Object Reference not set to an instance of an object' error upon debugging.

I cannot load my page nor get any breaks to occur. It seems to be failing when it tries to do an Application insights request GET of my form page.  It then throws an unhanded exception in System.Web.dll

However, that being said, when I try to run he debugger, I'm still met with a 'Object Reference not set to an instance of an object' error, but it references `BotDetect.Web.UI.WebFormsCaptcha.OnInit(EventArgs e)`

I've removed the BotDetect package, re-added the assemblies, tried to add the assemblies from the working project, and I've tried to recreate the project from the ground up to see if I maybe had mis-configured something.  Nothing seems to work.

I currently have `BotDetect` and `BotDetect.Web.MVC` from the NuGet package (version 4.0.1) and I've checked to make sure I'm using the .net 4.5 versions with my .net 4.5 project.

I've checked my Packages.config and I can see:

```
<package id="Captcha" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Below is my code that references the BotDetect Captcha.  It is a MasterPage web form, but the Captcha resides in a content placeholder since we interact with it after the master has been rendered.

I'm just not sure what else I can do to fix this, any suggestions?

**ASP Form Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
<fieldset>
  <legend>ASP.NET WebForm CAPTCHA Validation</legend>
  <p class="prompt">
    <label for="CaptchaCodeTextBox">Retype the characters from the picture:</label></p>
  <BotDetect:WebFormsCaptcha runat="server" ID="ExampleCaptcha" 
  UserInputControlID="CaptchaCodeTextBox" />
  <div class="validationDiv">
    <asp:TextBox ID="CaptchaCodeTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="ValidateCaptchaButton" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="CaptchaCorrectLabel" runat="server" CssClass="correct"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="CaptchaIncorrectLabel" runat="server" CssClass="incorrect"></asp:Label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**ASP Form Page CODE BEHIND**

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    ' initial page setup
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' set control text
        ValidateCaptchaButton.Text = "Validate"
        CaptchaCorrectLabel.Text = "Correct!"
        CaptchaIncorrectLabel.Text = "Incorrect!"

        ' these messages are shown only after validation
        CaptchaCorrectLabel.Visible = False
        CaptchaIncorrectLabel.Visible = False
    End If

    If IsPostBack Then
        ' validate the Captcha to check we're not dealing with a bot
        Dim isHuman As Boolean
        isHuman = ExampleCaptcha.Validate()
        If isHuman Then
            CaptchaCorrectLabel.Visible = True
            CaptchaIncorrectLabel.Visible = False
        Else
            CaptchaCorrectLabel.Visible = False
            CaptchaIncorrectLabel.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim HF As HiddenField = DirectCast(Page.Master.FindControl("HF1"), HiddenField)

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            SetInitialRow()
        ElseIf HF.Value = "AddNewRow" Then
            AddNewRowToGrid()
        Else
            btnSubmit_Click()
        End If
Done:
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do yo understand what that exception means?

Comment: In reference to variables and functions not being available, yes.  For this error however, I am unsure.  As I stated above, it's not loading the project so I assume it has something to do with a reference not being set in one of the assemblies. Upon checking the assembly  for BotDetect, I can see that BotDetect.Web.UI.WebFormsCaptcha.OnInit(EventArgs e) indeed exists.  This is clearly something before page load though, that much I do know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've since spoken to the devs of BotDetect and it turned out that this is in fact a bug with their current release.

You currently cannot set the UserInputControlID property in a content page (Web form with master page) with BotDetect (v4.0.1).  There will be a patch for this in the next version.

In the meantime, based on the code I posted, you can set it programmatically in the codebehind (VB).

> **CODE BEHIND (in page_prerender)**

`ExampleCaptcha.UserInputID = CaptchaCodeTextBox.ClientID`

*You may also need to replace*

```
isHuman = ExampleCaptcha.Validate()
```

*With*

```
isHuman = ExampleCaptcha.Validate(CaptchaCodeTextBox.Text.Trim())
```

> **CONTENT WEB FORM**

```
<BotDetect:WebFormsCaptcha runat="server" ID="ExampleCaptcha" />
```